# Python Skype bot won't send messages sometimes

Tags: python, performance, skype4py

I've started coding a Skype bot as my first Python project. It works pretty well when it actually sends the messages, but sometimes it completely doesn't send a message. I'm not sure if it's because of me writing it poorly or because of my Internet connection.

`botfuncs` is the one that usually fails to send a message in [my code](http://pastebin.com/57rae28X):

```
def botfuncs():
    def OnMessageStatus(Message, Status):
        if Status == 'RECEIVED':
            c = Message.Body
            if Message.Body.lower() == "time":
                client.SendMessage(Message.FromHandle, "The current time is {0}".format(time.strftime("%Y, %b %d, %H:%M:%S.")))
            elif c[0:4].lower() == "sudo":
                client.SendMessage(Message.FromHandle, c[5:])
    client.OnMessageStatus = OnMessageStatus
```

Comment: Post the code here please so we can see it easily.

Comment: I don't believe `sayhi` and `cheese` actually send a message. Between `msg`, `stringchecker` and `botfuncs`, which of those sometimes fail to send a message?

Comment: `botfuncs` usually fails to send a message to the person it's supposed to.

Comment: Right, sorry about that.